# Hibernate OptimisticLocking not working

Tags: hibernate, spring, optimistic-locking

I am using Hibernate 3.6.6 with Sping 3.0.4
After adding

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(optimisticLock=OptimisticLockType.ALL, dynamicUpdate=true)
```

to my bean and running following testcase

```
SSNConceptDAO conceptDao = (SSNConceptDAO)Context.getBean("conceptDAO");
SSNConcept ssnConcept = conceptDao.findById(9000000612l);
ssnConcept.setEditornote("Editor Note at "+System.currentTimeMillis());
conceptDao.update(ssnConcept);
```

Hibernate Don't add proper WHERE Clause to the update statement

However in an other application I am only using Hibernate without Spring, same settings are working perfectly alright.

Comment: What does optimistic-locking have to do with adding a WHERE clause to the update statement?

Comment: Is your test case is just a JUNIT test case? I cannot see any transaction demarcation around your code